# c++ loose coupling function dependency

Tags: c++, architecture, decoupling, loose-coupling

As the title already might suggest I am having a hard time describing my architectural problem and for the same reason searching has been without result. I am writing a command line application which aims to take in two-dimensional data to which a physics model can be fitted by means of least squares fitting. I already have implemented a Nelder-Mead and Levenberg-Marquardt routine that work properly, i.e. given a set of data, a model and cost function, they will optimize an array of fitting parameters.

For this purpose I want to write a class that facilitates the abstract functionality of optimization, independent of the actual model and cost function that will be used.

```
class Fit
{
public:
    Fit();
    ~Fit();

    run();

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> m_data;
    std::vector<double> m_parameters;
    std::vector<double> m_evaluated;
}
```

The actual optimization method `run()` will look roughly like the following:

```
void run()
{
    // Set initial guess for parameters
    m_parameters = {...};

    while(condition) {
        double cost_value;
        // Evaluate model function for current parameters
        (*model)(&m_evaluated, m_data, m_parameters);
        (*cost)(&cost_value, m_data, m_evaluated);

        if (cost_value < threshold_value)
            break;
        else
            update_parameters(&m_parameters);
    }
}
```

This is where my questions comes in. The `Fit::run()` method needs to call a `model` and `cost` function but there is no knowing up front what these will look like or what function arguments they require. The arguments that they take in my example are the bare minimum required arguments as seen from the fitting procedure but there might be additional required arguments.

Specific cost functions and model will be defined elsewhere but I have no clue how to let the `Fit` class know which functions it needs to call. Coming from `c` I was thinking function pointers but I have no clue how this is most preferably done in `c++`. Should `Fit` have a function pointer member `m_model` that has to be set after it is instantiated? I am just spitballing here. How would I best approach this and what is this problem called so I could maybe look for additional approaches?

Edit: to give a better idea of what I am trying to accomplish some pseudo code.

```
// Imagine multiple available functions that all work differently but take some array of parameters 
// which is then used to evaluate some function for a set of data values
void model_a(std::vector<double>* y, std::vector<std::vector<double>> data, std::vector<double> p) {
    for (int i; i < data[0].size(); ++i)
        (*y)[i] = parameters[0] + parameters[1]*data[0][i];
};

void model_b(std::vector<double>* y, std::vector<std::vector<double>> data, std::vector<double> p) {
    for (int i; i < data[0].size(); ++i)
        (*y)[i] = parameters[0] - pow(data[0][i], parameters[1]);
};

// Assume we have some data
std::vector<std::vector<double>> data = {};

Fit fit = Fit();
fit->set_data(data)
fit->set_model(model_a); // This is what the question is about
fit->run();

// Now we can extract and display the optimized parameter array
std::vector<double> p = fit.parameters();
for (int i; i < p.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << p[i] << std::endl;
```

Comment: _"Coming from c I was thinking function pointers but I have no clue how this is most preferably done in c++."_ The common way in c++ is [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: It would be very helpful if the downvoter could explain why he thinks this question is not worth asking

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the reason may be your question is actually a bit broad, and you didn't provide such a clear code example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: The reason I kept it relatively broad was deliberate because this struck me as a particular problem that should occur often and I did not want to clutter the problem with details. I will edit in a piece of pseudo code that should clarify what I would like to accomplish

Comment: _"How would I best approach this ..."_ Also note, this leaves room for opinionated answers, which is also off-topic.

Comment: I see and appreciate that, but I want to prevent starting with some approach based on a pure guess and then run into trouble later at which point I will probably start asking [XY-questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Would you know an other stackexchange forum that might be better suited forum for this question?

Comment: As for your edits, note that `std::function` mentioned from my 1st comment, also might work well with [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).  The approach passing the parameter list as `std::vector` is a good idea already.

Answer (score 0):

To me, this sounds like you either want an interface class that provides the interface, or simply making a class hieararchy, where the data is stored in a base-class, and the derived class knows how to calculate the cost, etc.

There are several ways that you can actually implement this - if you want the data to persist within the class, you could pass in either at construction or later, in instance of the cost model.

Unfortunately, I have to rush now, but will be back later to check in for comments, etc.